# Webserver on termux browser said " you dont have permision to accses resource"

Tags: termux, termux-linux

i was installed web dev package termux on my android phone, the package are included apache ,php,phpmyadmin, but , when i run localhost:8080 on browser , it said i dont have permison to use resources.

Anyone experince with this ? What should i do then..